# Spring security: Can not access target page after entering proper credentials

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to create a basic Spring Security (3.0) application following the common tutorials from internet. However, even after entering configured credentials, login page is opening again. The debug logs show that the user is being authenticated as anonymous user. Please let me know what I am missing.

Here's my web.xml:-

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring Security Example</display-name>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

My spring-security.xml:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <http >
        <intercept-url pattern="/app/*"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/app/login/"
            default-target-url="/app/home/"
            authentication-failure-url="/app/login?error=true" />
    </http>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="sumit" password="1234"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

My login.jsp:-

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login page</h2>


    <form:form method="POST" action="../home" commandName="user">
        Username: <form:input path="username" />
        <br>

        Password: <form:input path="password" />
        <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form:form>



</body>
</html>
```

My Controller:-

```
package com.test.basicspring.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.test.model.UserModel;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/app")
public class HelloWorldController {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hello")
    public void SayHello(HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        logger.info("Logging Hello World");
        try {
            response.getWriter().write("Request completed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/login")
    public String login(Model modelMap) {
        System.out.println("In login method");
        modelMap.addAttribute("user", new UserModel());
        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("Login successful");
        return "";

    }

}
```

Debug logs after submitting login credentials:-

```
    DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,856 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/app/home'; to: '/app/home'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,856 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - Candidate is: '/app/home'; pattern is /**; matched=true
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,856 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /app/home at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@26f6ad34'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,856 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,856 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@4f884b44. A new one will be created.
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,856 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /app/home at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7d0a1070'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,856 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /app/home at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@542dcf66'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,856 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest  - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest  - queryString: both null (property equals)
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest  - requestURI: arg1=/springSecurityExample/app/hello; arg2=/springSecurityExample/app/home (property not equals)
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache  - saved request doesn't match
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /app/home at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6d55a0ba'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /app/home at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6ec0b31f'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fabe8e0: Principal: anonymousUser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe9938: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: F09C61DDA9D42B649B89CD650863A289; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /app/home at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1f29202'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /app/home at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@77240701'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /app/home at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@72e500b4'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource  - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/app/home'; to: '/app/home'
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource  - Candidate is: '/app/home'; pattern is /app/*; matched=true
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /app/home; Attributes: [ROLE_USER]
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fabe8e0: Principal: anonymousUser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe9938: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: F09C61DDA9D42B649B89CD650863A289; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased  - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@4bb7d66d, returned: -1
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased  - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@eb5417f, returned: 0
TRACE   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /app/home]
DEBUG   2020-01-18 10:51:36,857 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use such an old version of Spring Security?

Comment: @AnarSultanov I have started learning spring security recently. I wanted to create a very basic application first just to make sure that I do not miss anything related to configuration. I am planning to upgrade spring version step by step.

Comment: I would advise you to start by studying the new version and refer to the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: It's a very old spring security version (as @AnarSultanov stated). In any case on first view in your login form the action must point to login and not to ../home

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Thanks. It was one of the points where I was confused. So, I also need to create a Request mapping method in controller as "login" and type POST? I had created one with mapping as "home" now. Also, why does the name "login" or "home" matter?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I have also added code for controller now. Please check my previous comment.

Comment: You should not create the login controller. It should be managed by spring. It matters if you use home o login. In any case you must tell spring if the login URL is login or home. You may start from here https://github.com/angeloimm/arcacontext it's not the lates spring security version but it gives to you a full working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make above code work by specifying `action` attribute and `login-processing-url` both to `'/login'`. With this configuration, spring activates inbuilt filter for username and password validation. Then, it goes to endpoint specified by `default-target-url`.